# How much does system RAM matter for Litecoin mining?

Tags: mining-hardware, scrypt, mining-technical-details, memory

I know your system RAM cannot be smaller than your GPU RAM for LTC mining, but other than that, is it a problem if you have like only 2GB of RAM?

Answer (score 1):

i have 3 7950s with 3gb of ram each and only 2gb in the machine, it would work even with 1 gb i think

there was a bug with an older version of openCL or cgminer (cant remember) that did use pc ram instead of gpu.